# Invalid object name after pushing to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I am running a **Database First** application. Everything works beautifully until I push to azure, but azure seems to be trying to pluralize one of the table names that should not be pluralized.

### Error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.ProductAttributePriceAdjustments'.
```

The table name is actually **ProductAttributePriceAdjustment**

I am not very familiar with the database first approach, how can I keep azure from trying to do this? Most (if not all) of the other tables have pluralized names, so I can't turn off pluralizing as a whole.

What should I do?

**Relevant EntityMapping from edmx file**

```
<EntitySetMapping Name="ProductAttributePriceAdjustments">
    <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="RPSModel.ProductAttributePriceAdjustment">
      <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ProductAttributePriceAdjustment">
        <ScalarProperty Name="AdjustmentId" ColumnName="AdjustmentId" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="StoreProductId" ColumnName="StoreProductId" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="StoreId" ColumnName="StoreId" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="ProductId" ColumnName="ProductId" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="ProductSizeId" ColumnName="ProductSizeId" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="Adjustment" ColumnName="Adjustment" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="PointsAdjustment" ColumnName="PointsAdjustment" />
        <ScalarProperty Name="ProductColorID" ColumnName="ProductColorID" />
      </MappingFragment>
    </EntityTypeMapping>
</EntitySetMapping>
```

#### Context

```
public partial class RPSEntities : DbContext
{
    public RPSEntities()
        : base("name=RPSEntities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AdjustmentPriceTracking> AdjustmentPriceTrackings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientLogo> ClientLogos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConfirmationNumber> ConfirmationNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CreditCardOrderDetail> CreditCardOrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemCodeException> ItemCodeExceptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Logo> Logos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewUserLoad> NewUserLoads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderShippingAddress> OrderShippingAddresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductAttributePriceAdjustment> ProductAttributePriceAdjustments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReceiptRecipient> ReceiptRecipients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SSIS_Configuration> SSIS_Configurations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreGroup> StoreGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreInfoProduct> StoreInfoProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductColor> StoreProductColors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductGroup> StoreProductGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductImage> StoreProductImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductPatchAssignment> StoreProductPatchAssignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductPricing> StoreProductPricings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProduct> StoreProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreProductSize> StoreProductSizes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreSlideshowImage> StoreSlideshowImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreType> StoreTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreUserPoint> StoreUserPoints { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoreUser> StoreUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TempCCUserImport> TempCCUserImports { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in EF, but from your mapping, I can see tah you use <EntitySetMapping Name="ProductAttributePriceAdjustments">, which sets the name in plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that that after pushing to azure this was trying to run Code-First. Instead of specifying a standard azure connection sting through the azure configuration, I hard coded the string in the web config, then everything worked.